# Apache webserver error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

i am running my ruby on rails application on a `mac os x 10.7` on `Apache Web Server` with `Passenger` plugin. My `httpd.conf` file is as follows.

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/Ahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/Ahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19
PassengerRuby /Users/Ahmad/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p392/ruby
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName qchext.local
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot "/Users/Ahmad/Sites/redbytes_projects/qchext/public"    
  <Directory "/Users/Ahmad/Sites/redbytes_projects/qchext/public">
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
ServerName qchext.local
```

**error_log** file

```
[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[notice] Digest: done
[warn] mod_bonjour: Skipping user 'Ahmad' - no valid index file. 
[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.19 DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal  operations
```

Please guide me what wrong i ve done.

Comment: Are you running from OSX?

Answer (score 0):

The `SIGTERM` you see is used to restart Apache, did you install the latest Apache with `mod_passenger` and not the Apache that comes bundled with OSX (Assuming that this is what you are running RoR on).

Comment: ohh i ve forgotten to update it. What must be my step to install the latest apache version ?

Comment: That all depends on your setup. If you use `macports`, you could install it with `port install apache`

Comment: Google for updating Apache then, point is you should run the latest version.

Comment: The version i m using is
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 12 2012 15:11:26

Comment: Do you have the latest mod_passenger?

Comment: yeah i ve installed it yesterday only.